# Adding auto complete for OpenCV in PyScripter

Tags: opencv, intellisense, pyscripter

I have just started using PyScripter. I do not get any autocomplete options when I am using `cv` or `cv2` module!
How can I update my intellisense for OpenCV ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know whether it is the correct solution to this problem or not but this is what I tried and it was successful:

1. Go to `Tools ---> Options ---> IDE Options`
2. Then in the `Code Completion` part add `cv2` to `Special Packages`

This enabled the auto-complete for `opencv` in the editor!

Answer (score 0):

Note that 10 years later, this is now (v 4.2.5) under

> Tools | Options | IDE Options | **Language Server** | Special Packages